# My co-workers do not invite me regulary to coffee, after the work

Tags: communication, colleagues, relationships

After work, my co-workers usually go to grab a coffee or some drinks. They all go together, and I was invited only a couple of times. I have been employed there for a couple of months now.  I would like to have a good relationship with them, so what can I do to be included more often?

A couple of times I went with them and it was really awkward. I didn’t really know what to talk about with them or how to join in on the conversation, so it would be less awkward. Personally, I am reserved, self-conscious, and socially awkward, so sometimes I don’t know what to say.

What can I do, and how must I behave to make them accept me more in their social circle?

Comment: For context is this the whole office, everyone else on your team or just a small group from your office?

Comment: @DevMoutarde Gelling with your team is a workplace issue. The workplace isn't just about how many widgets we churn out or what some policy or manager has done. It's also about finding our place in a team to facilitate those other things.

Comment: Its not getting with your team here but rather getting with people. Whatever.

Comment: Can you include more details of how many of your coworkers go and how many coworkers you have? If you have just 2 coworkers, it might be perfectly normal for them being close friends and it might be seen as weird if you try to go with them, if it's a group of 10-20 random people from your office depending on who has the time after work on each day, then it's something else entirely.

Comment: @nvoigt, OP mentioned "they all" which suggests more than two.

Comment: @Dedwards I have been on a team where 4 of 5 people where real life friends and would talk about their evening plans openly. Does not mean that #5 would have fit in. And no amount of "interpersonal skills" or "workplace behavior" would have fixed that. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: @nvoigt If those 4 people don't want number 5 to come, then they shouldn't openly talk about such plan in front of them.

Comment: @thelem I don't really understand. Why would I not talk to a friend when someone is around? I do that all the time and I see other people do that all the time. Just because A asks B if they want to go to the movies does not imply I should feel invited, just because I'm in range to hear them.

Comment: @nvoigt If two people in a team of five make plans together, fair enough. If four people make plans then it becomes an unofficial team gathering and you're excluding the fifth person if they are not welcome.

Comment: @nvoigt this group includes five people. They have worked at this place longer than me. I am the youngest of the group

Answer (score 24):

Have you tried asking?

Next time you hear them talking about going for coffee or drinks, just try asking "Do you mind if I join you?"

In most cases, once you've been invited a couple of times, people just assume you know that you're welcome and stop actively inviting you. If you're quiet and introverted you may be feeling awkwardness that the group itself doesn't notice.

Unless you specifically aggravated someone in your last trips, they probably have just grown accustomed to you being around and aren't making a concerted effort any longer.

They may be just as worried as you are about not imposing, and they don't want to put you in an awkward place between seeming rude for turning down an invitation and forcing you to go on an outing after work. If you express interest in going, they'll know you really do want to go and aren't just being nice because they asked.

Show an interest in being included and they will likely show an interest in including you.

Comment: To add a bit, as the new person you were specifically invited to join in the the custom.  After that, it's usually the case that no one is actually 'invited' someone just announces the time/place and leaves it at that.  Whoever goes goes.

Comment: To celebrate being new, or a birthday, or because it's spring, ask if you can come too because you want to treat them all to coffee and snacks. It breaks the ice nicely.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps read "How to win Friends and Influence People".
Its a pretty solid book on how to be a bit more out going, and how to get around the "i dont know what to talk about" mindset.

Comment: Not really an answer on it's own. Perhaps you can discuss a bit more about the chapters you are referring to?

Comment: @jesse This is exactly what I was thinking, OP got invited, it was awkward, they stop inviting him. A part of the book explain how to increase social skills to make social event less awkward. Trying to get invited without social skills will probably make the event more awkward, I would recommend OP to let it go, stopping any plan to get invited for the moment. When his social skills we be better, he will probably receive a new invitation.

Answer (score 0):

You can deliberately practice improving talking with anyone.

1. As has been said, just ask.
2. Think of things to say in advance. Mostly avoid work topics so you can branch out.  Avoid politics. Consider sports, movies, weather.
3. Practice active listening. You can read about that think of it as a social skill. 
   https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_listening
4. Practice smiling in the mirror. Don't be shy about it.
5. Relax. Don't be anxious. Don't fill up your head with too many things.  Keep your conversational gambits simple and think later about what goes well and where to improve.